# treelite cannot be intsalled within conda with pip

Tags: python, conda

I have following .yml file:

```
name: data_science_env_prob3
channels:
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - openssl=1.1.1
  - pandas=0.23.4=py37h6440ff4_0
  - scikit-learn=0.19.2=py37h4f467ca_0
  - pip:
    - treelite==0.32
    - urllib3==1.24.1
    - xgboost==0.71
```

And when I try to create an environemnt

```
conda env create -f data_science_env.yml
```

, it throws an error:

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement treelite==0.32 (from -r /path/condaenv.ijla7f1z.requirements.txt (line 17)) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for treelite==0.32 (from -r /path/condaenv.ijla7f1z.requirements.txt (line 17))
```

However, I can install treelite  (not in conda env) with

```
pip install treelite
```

How can I install treelite with conda .yml file?

EDIT:
I created an env without treelite and then was able to install treelite with following:

```
pip3 install --user treelite
```

but with following it failed:

```
 pip install --user treelite
Collecting treelite
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement treelite (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for treelite
```

Comment: I have tried to install `treelite`from a conda environment with python 3.7 and pip couldn't find it. Maybe you should use python 3.6 because many package doesn't support 3.7 yet.

Comment: You should really check `which pip` and `which pip3`. It's likely the former is using the env's pip, whereas the latter is resolving back to your system's pip (even with env active) and therefore is still not installing in the env.

Answer (score 0):

Treelite is not currently available through pip for Python 3.7.

You will either need to install from source or switch to a Python 3.7 enviornment.